# Symfony2 ESI fragments add multiple session cookies

Tags: symfony, session

I have a page cached by Symfony Gateway cache that renders controllers using ESI-tags. Everything works fine except that every rendered fragment seems to add a Set-Cookie header for the session id. As it seems the session is also written several times, I see lines like

`Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []`

several times (once per cookie) in my log. Using FOSUserBundle and Memcached as session storage.

Since the cookie is stored in Memcached, Symfony opens a connection every time which is quite annoying.

Any idea how to get around that problem?

Comment: Are your ESI requests anonymous? Is varnish removing cooking from ESI requests?

Comment: The user is anonymous, we're using the builtin Symfony gateway cache.